# How to pass variables in the path of spark.read.csv with PySpark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark to read every day a csv file called something like AA_"current_date" where of course "current_date" changes every day.

The problem is that inside the path of spark.read.csv I would like to put a variable like `/AA_$current_date.csv` but I don't really now how to achieve this.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: can you provide how you are getting current date and also sample file name

Comment: you can use variable concatenation to read.csv like this  spark.read.csv(date_1+".csv")

Comment: Hi @MaheshGupta. Thanks for your comment. Could you provide more details about it? The problem is that I don't know how to work with variables in PySpark and your comment seems to go in the right direction

Comment: I tried something like spark.read.csv("first_part of path"+date) where date = str(date_format(current_date(),'YYYYMM'))+str(".csv") but it gives me error.

Comment: @WorkBench why you need where condition after reading csv file

Comment: No this was a misunderstanding, I have written "where" only to show you how date was defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> today = date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
>>> path = "AA_" + today + ".csv"
>>> base_path = "/home/user/"
>>> finalpath = base_path + path
>>> finalpath
'/home/user/AA_26-09-2019.csv'
>>> df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load(finalpath)
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. At the moment it seems to work, but give me some time please. In the meantime, may I ask you why defining  date as date = str(date_format(current_date(),'YYYYMM'))+str(".csv") and applying it to spark.read.csv("first_part of path"+date) produces error? I don't see any mistake in my code.

Comment: I don't think you are using correct way to format date in python. date_format is not work in python as I know. It work in Java or Scala.